# How to create a hierarchy of categories and subcategories with ENUMs in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to create a hierarchy of `categories` and `subcategories`.  The `ENUM` type makes the most sense to me, but I am trying to figure out how to create the tables to model my data.  I have a list of `categories`.  I also have a list of `subcategories` that are going to be in a 1 to many relation with the category.  Here are my `ENUM`s.

```
CREATE TYPE categories as ENUM('Casting', 'Cutting');
CREATE TYPE casting_subs as ENUM('Composite', 'Metal', 'Plastic', 'Rubber', 'Foam');
CREATE TYPE cutting_subs as ENUM('Die Cutting', 'Flame', 'Laser', 'Plasma', 'Saw', 'Waterjet');
```

How do I create the tables that models my data?

Comment: I think you forgot to finish typing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an enum here makes very little sense, actually. You're doing it correctly already if that is what you *really* want, i.e. without a table. What you probably want instead is a hierarchical table:

```
create table categories (
  id serial primary key,
  parent int references categories (id),
  name varchar not null
);
```

Start filling it like:

```
insert into categories (name)
values ('Casting'), ('Cutting');
```

Then fill subcategories using their relevant id, like:

```
insert into categories (parent, name)
values (1, 'Composite'), (1, 'Metal');
```

To query the full hierarchy, you can use a CTE:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html